# Update field in array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a record which contains an array and I want to update a specific field, in this example 'role'.

```json
{
 "_id": { "$oid":"..." },
 "members": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6468986c058476e181c36b17"
        },
        "since": "...",
        "role": "admin"
    }]
}
```

I'm using Go and my attempt to update the role field to be 'user' looks like this:

```go
    filter := bson.M{"_id": id, "members.id": memberID}
    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "members.$.role": "user",
        },
    }

    account.FindOneAndUpdate(s.db.ctx, filter, update)
}
```

My understanding is that the `filter` on `members.id` will find the matching member ID within the `members` array and `members.$.role` will update that found members role. What am I missing?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/

Comment: I've seen the link, which is where I learned about using the positional `$` operator and that the query must be for the array field, which I believe I have correct. Still not sure what I'm doing wrong to update the field within the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update specific values in an array, using `$` operator, you need to pass `arrayFilters` option in the third parameter to the `update` function. Like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "12122323"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "members.$[element].role": "value"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "element._id": ObjectId("6468986c058476e181c36b17")
    }
  ]
})
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ui3r4HLh_HT)
Go through this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/#multiple-array-elements) to transform it into the `Go` equivalent mongo query.